# How does Flask-Admin SecureForm and CSRF protection work

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms, flask-admin

I'm currently writing a simple blog application using Flask-Admin for administrative tasks. I'd like to enable CSRF protection and have followed the instructions on the [Advanced Functionality](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/) page in the docs.

However, this doesn't seem to prevent my dummy CSRF attacks from succeeding and it is unclear how Flask-Admin follows the [CSRF protection](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/csrf.html) implementation outlined in the WTForms documentation.

Regarding my dummy CSRF attacks, my method follows the example for POST requests suggested in the [OWASP CSRF article](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)):

```
<body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
<form action="http://localhost:5000/admin/blogpost/new?url=%2Fadmin%2Fblogpost%2F" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="title" value="Evil title"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="content" value="Evil content"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

where the action address is the new post creation page that draws from the create.html template of Flask-Admin.

When I load the malicious form from a [separate origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) (localhost:3000) and submit it on document load, I find that the request goes through despite the form being configured with the Flask-Admin SecureForm setup linked above.

I've tried consulting the Flask-Admin source code, but couldn't find the WTForms csrf_token in the relevant templates, though the SecureForm includes the CSRF settings as expected.

Does Flask-Admin diverge from the documented WTForms implementation of CSRF protection? If so, how?

More practically speaking, is there any additional configuration beyond the use of Flask-Admin's SecureForm in my ModelView-based classes necessary to enable CSRF protection?

Note also that the technique described in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/67630/how-can-we-find-the-csrf-vulnerability-in-a-website#67631) also worked for me in my attempts to use exposed admin URLs cross-site (again from localhost:3000) to perform actions requiring authentication.

This leads me to ask the follow-up: is it possible to implement CSRF on non-form Flask-Admin pages, i.e. for GET requests, to protect exposed admin URLs used for operations such as logout or account deletion operations?